# How did Talia find her father?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In the great revelation of The Dark Knight Rises, we are shown it was Talia who escaped The Pit, then brought her father back to rescue her savior, Bane.

However, considering the fact that Talia was born and raised in the prison, how did she know where to find her father or who he was?

One can assume that her mother instructed her on her father's name and nature of his profession, but it is reasonable to believe that her mother didn't know where Ra's was since her incarceration?

Comment: I think that the movie Taken explains this. Ra's found her.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it's more about how Ra's Al Ghul found his daughter rather than a matter of her finding him. The news of a child escaping the pit would have spread fast and must have reached to Ra's Al Ghul. He must have tried to contact the person who escaped the pit in order to make her join league of shadows and in that process he may have came to know she is his daughter. 
I have to admit that I am not familiar with comics and this is the most logical explanation that came to my mind!

Comment: I know everyone loves Christopher Nolan, but I think you can just chalk this one up to "plot hole". The fact that we have to infer so much tells me why it couldn't be anything but.

Answer (score -2):

*ahem*

There's these things called telephones.  In the era before cheap, pay-as-you-go cells (aka 'burners'), you were restricted to landlines.  To set up clandestine calls, have someone call a payphone.  In the advent that you want a more 'permanent' solution, have a 'retired' member maintain a phoneline, have people call them, and then the lieutenant calls whatever number you've last set up for them, passing on the message.

Here's how I see the last conversation between Ra's and Talia's mother going:

```
"Ra's, Daddy's at the door!"  
"Oh dear - I'll try to escape, but we should meet up afterwards"
"But how will I find you?  You'll have to leave the country!"
"Here, take this phone number.  Tell the person on the other end where you are."
"Goodbye, take care!"
```

Obviously, her mother never got to make that phone call (or some variation on passing messages this way), but she could have told *Talia* how to find her father.

Comment: But we're talking an unknown time (assuming Talia is close to Bruce's age [39] and TDKR is set in 2012, that would make her escape close to 1980) in the middle of nowhere in Morocco.  Now, I'm not sure how up to date their technology is [pure ignorance on the subject] but either way, I'm sure Ra's did not have something as a *telephone* that is a direct line to him...

Comment: Casablanca is in Morocco, which is also next to Algeria (which was European controlled through WWII).  Even if some parts of the backcountry didn't have (complete) phone coverage, there will still be phones in some places.  And I doubt that Talia would have had a direct line anyways.  Either she called somebody who would have a direct line, or potentially Ra's had previously left men nearby (retired) that Talia had been told about.